# Postgres is running, but psql won't connect to it

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgresql@11 installed and running.

```
% brew services restart postgresql@11
Stopping `postgresql@11`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@11` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@11)
==> Successfully started `postgresql@11` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@11)
```

But

```
% psql -d template1                     
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And

```
% which psql
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@11/bin/psql
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Please add which access you opened on your postgresql server.